# I can't modify Security settings of OS

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, security

After a reboot, I cannot configure my normal VPN connection, nor modify some Operating System security settings.

What can prevent me from making changes to security settings? Malware?

Comment: Should this question be closed? Or rewritten in a format of **question**: _vague but index- & search-able observations_ with an **answer**: _description of underlying issue and solution for that issue_.

Comment: No need to close the question. You did a good job following SE's Q&A format. This might be useful for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applications which interfere with screen appearance can prevent a user from makes changes to security settings while the app is active.

The operating system has to be careful to prevent a 3rd-party application from having influence over security settings by changing the appearance of security options to the user. (best guess speculation)

A screen-color-changing app, Twilight, may have been active, and therefore, from a Security Manager's point of view, able to influence a user's input to system security settings menus.